# Retain a value defined inside of a while statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to use the value assigned to the variable BinId outside of the while statement as below:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT max(binID) from bin";
MySqlDataReader idReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int BinId;

while (idReader.Read())
{
    BinId = idReader.GetInt32(0);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(BinId);
}
```

is there a way I can do this?

Edit: This is what I'm trying to do with BinId

`cmd.CommandText = "insert into mydb1.missedbin values (null, '" + personIDdata + "','" + dateFound + "','"+ BinId +"')";`

Comment: Where is "where" statement, that has variable BinId?

Comment: Sorry, was supposed to write while, have edited.

Comment: Post an example of code that is not working, so that we can understand what is your goal. Because the way you phrase it, it should just work

Comment: Have edited to include the insert i'm trying to do outside of the while.

Comment: Which side of the loop? before or after?

Comment: after @MichaelPeyper

Comment: @Richard1996, BinId should be accessible outside the while loop. You have declared BinId in method scope probably and should be accessible in method, if you want to you in different method then declare at class scope as a data member.

Comment: @Adil you are correct, I have it in a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change `while` to `if`. This is because you are only getting a single value so there is no need for a while, there will only ever be 1 record. You should also check the value of the resulting `binId` to ensure it is a positive number (which I assume would be the expected result if there is a record).

```
int BinId = 0;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT max(binID) from bin";

// wrap your reader in a using block
using(MySqlDataReader idReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (idReader.Read())
    {
        BinId = idReader.GetInt32(0);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(BinId);
    }
    if(BinId < 1)
        return; // You did not get a value so exit your method or do something....
}

// NOTE: DO NOT DO THIS, always use parameterized queries
cmd.CommandText = "insert into mydb1.missedbin values (null, '" + personIDdata + "','" + dateFound + "','"+ BinId +"')";
```

About your insert statement, do not write queries like this ever. Always use parameterized queries.

Comment: It still seems to be unassigned outside of the if statement.